# Assigning Equipped Items to Player Characters in Text Adventure game?

Tags: c++, game-engine, text-based, adventure

I'm creating a text-based adventure game and Im a bit confused on how to actually assign a weapon object to a player. I'm inputting weapons from a text file called `weapons.txt`:

```
ID: 1.
Weapon Name: Katana.
Damage: 20.
Weight: 6.

ID: 2.
Weapon Name: Longsword.
Damage: 17.
Weight: 9.

ID: 3.
Weapon Name: WarAxe.
Damage: 22.
Weight: 20.

ID: 4.
Weapon Name: Staff.
Damage: 9.
Weight: 6.
```

And I have written a player and weapons class:

```
#include "Weapons.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
DoublyLinkedList<Weapons> weaponsList;
DoublyLinkedListIterator<Weapons> itr = weaponsList.getIterator();

Weapons :: Weapons() {
    this->weaponID = 0;
    this->weaponName = "";
    this->damage = 0;
    this->weight = 0;
}
Weapons :: Weapons(int weaponID,string weaponName,int damage,int weight) {
    this->weaponID = weaponID;
    this->weaponName = weaponName;
    this->damage = damage;
    this->weight = weight;
}
int Weapons :: getWeaponID() {
    return weaponID;
}
string Weapons :: getWeaponName() {
    return weaponName;
}
void Weapons::setWeaponName(string weaponName) {
    this->weaponName = weaponName;
}
int Weapons :: getDamage() {
    return damage;
}
int Weapons :: getWeight() {
    return weight;
}
void Weapons :: getWeapons() {
    string fileName = "Weapons\\Weapons.txt";
    ifstream infile(fileName);
    string garbage;
    int id;
    string weapon;
    int damage;
    int weight;
    while(infile >> garbage >> id >> garbage >> garbage
        >> garbage >> weapon >> garbage >> damage >> garbage
        >> garbage >> weight >> garbage) {
        cout << "ID: \t\t\t"<< id << "\n";
        cout << "Weapon Name: \t\t"<< weapon << "\n";
        cout << "Damage: \t\t" << damage <<"\n";
        cout << "Weight: \t\t" << weight << "\n";
        Weapons w1 (id,weapon,damage,weight);
        weaponsList.Append(w1);
    }
}
void Weapons :: printWeapons() {
    int index = 0;
    //Loop through the iterator.
    for(itr.Start();itr.Valid();itr.Forth()) {
        index++;
        cout << "------------------Weapon------------------\n";
        cout << "--------------------------------\n";
        cout << "Position:\t\t" << index << "\n";
        cout << "--------------------------------\n";
        cout << "Weapon ID:\t\t" << itr.Item().getWeaponID() << "\n";
        cout << "Weapon Name:\t\t" << itr.Item().getWeaponName() << "\n";
        cout << "Damage:\t\t\t" << itr.Item().getDamage() << "\n";
        cout << "Weight:\t\t\t" << itr.Item().getWeight() << "\n";
        cout << "------------------------------------------\n";
    }
    cout << "Weapons: \t\t" << weaponsList.getCount() << "\n";
}

#include "Player.h"
#include "Validators.h"
#include <iostream>
Validators validators;
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:           Default Constructor.
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Player :: Player() {
    this->firstName = "";
    this->secondName = "";
    this->level = 0;
    this->experience = 0;
    this->strength = 0;
    this->weapons = weapons;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:           Full Constructor.
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Player :: Player(string firstName,string secondName,int level,int experience,int strength,Weapons weapons) {
    this->firstName = firstName;
    this->secondName = secondName;
    this->level = level;
    this->experience = experience;
    this->strength = strength;
    this->weapons = weapons;
    }
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Name:           Getters.
//  Description:    Makes you able to access the member variables of the player class.
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
string Player :: getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
void Player:: setFirstName(string firstName) {
    this->firstName = firstName;
}
string Player :: getSecondName() {
    return secondName;
}
int Player :: getLevel() {
    return level;
}
int Player :: getExperience() {
    return experience;
}
int Player :: getStrength() {
    return strength;
}
void Player :: playerCreation() {
    string inputFirstName = "Please enter your first name: ";
    firstName = validators.getString(inputFirstName);
    string inputSecondName = "Please enter your second name: ";
    secondName = validators.getString(inputSecondName);
    level = 0;
    experience = 0;
    strength = 8;
    weapons.getWeaponName();
}
void Player::loadPlayer() {
    //string fileName = "Players\\" + getFirstName()+ getSecondName() + ".txt";
    string fileName = "Players\\ConorPendlebury.txt";
    ifstream infile(fileName);
    string garbage;
    string loadFirstName;
    string loadLastName;
    int loadLevel;
    int loadExperience;
    int loadStrength;
    Weapons weapons;
    while(infile>>garbage,infile>>garbage,infile>>loadFirstName,infile>>garbage,
    infile>>garbage,infile>>loadLastName,infile>>garbage,infile>>loadLevel,
    infile>>garbage,infile>>loadExperience,infile>>garbage,infile>>loadStrength,infile>>garbage) {
        cout << "First Name: \t"<< loadFirstName << "\n";
        cout << "Second Name: \t"<< loadLastName << "\n";
        cout << "Level: \t\t" << loadLevel <<"\n";
        cout << "Experience: \t" << loadExperience << "\n";
        cout << "Strength: \t" << loadStrength << "\n";
    }
    //this->setFirstName(firstName);
}

void Player::savePlayer() {
    string fileName = "Players\\" + getFirstName()+ getSecondName() + ".txt";
    cout << "File: \t\t" << fileName << " was saved" << endl;
    ofstream oFile(fileName);
    oFile << "First Name: " << this->getFirstName() << endl;
    oFile << "Second Name: " << this->getSecondName() << endl;
    oFile << "Level: " << this->getLevel()<< endl;
    oFile << "Experience: " << this->getExperience()<< endl;
    oFile << "Strength: " << this->getStrength()<< endl;
    oFile << "Weapon: " << weapons.getWeaponName();
}
```

I am able to take the weapons from the file and add them to a Linkedlist but I'm stuck on how to assign certain weapons to the player before and after run-time.

Please can anybody help? Thanks.

Comment: Could you go through the sequence you want to follow. You load the weapon list first, and you create the player afterwards. And somehow you want to give the newly created player a weapon from the weapon list. Is that it?

Comment: In the `loadplayer` you can assign a weapon to the player if the player did'nt have any weapon. or in the default constructor you can initialize with a default weapon of your choice.

Comment: What do you mean by "... before and after run-time"? Your program only runs at run-time...

Comment: @john yes i think.  I basically wantg to load rooms,wepaons and objects etc... and then have a player set with a particular room and location and then be able to change the objects as i go through the game